# Java Console-Application: How to Pause a Scanner for a Sysout call

Tags: java, multithreading, bash, logging, console

I have a simple server application, which can be executed in the Windows Console (CMD).
After starting all services an connecting to the database the console prints „username@servername:~/$„ out, like a Linux bash.

[The Bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3HQl.jpg)

The user should call simple commands like „help“ „status“ „exit“,...

At the same time the Console should output some log/debug infos like new connection-attempts from clients, or errors while talking to the database,...

If I use a Scanner to catch these user input and the Logger logs a message to the console at the same time, the message gets printet right behind the bash (~/$) and the scanner will move to the next line without printing a new bash.

How I can handle these two thinks? 
The bash should always listen to a userinput, but there must be a way to log some messages at separate new line and print a new batch after this line and opening a new scanner for the next userinput.

My current attempts, like using a thread including a while loop an start and stop them, all ends with wired exception.

How I can handle this problem?

Comment: Not sure what you are wanting but it sounds like you need the input and output streams?  *all ends with wired exception.* - why don't you share your problem?

Comment: IMO, you need to run the program in the background like git. Share the exception would be much helpful.